# Spark DataFrame's `except()` removes different items every time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var df = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11).toDF("num")
df.show()
var df2 = df.limit(3)
df2.show()
var df3 =  df.except(df2)
df3.show()
```

Surprisingly, I found that except is not working the way it should. Here is my output:
df2: created correctly, contains 1,2 and 3. But my df3 still has 1, 2 and/or 3 in it. It's kind of random. If I run it multiple times, I get different result. Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: odd, I'm getting consistent (expected) results. What Spark version are you using, and what's your "cluster manager" (i.e. master - local / YARN / standalone, ...)

Comment: don't use var. try using val as much as possible.

Comment: this is not a good example to understand how spark works. You cannot assume that limit(3) will return 1,2,3. It will return just 3 elements but they could be collected from different machines. If you want to test this functionality just create different dataframes.

Comment: "Limit Returns a new Dataset by taking the first n rows." that's what I have found in the definition. Though I have no problem if it doesn't return the first 3. 
@Zohar, YARN 
Thanks for replying though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a spark "action" to collect the data that is required for "`df2`" before performing the "except" operation, which will ensure that the dataframe `df2` get computed before hand and has the fixed content which will be subtracted from `df`.

Randomness is because spark lazy evaluation and spark is putting all your code in one stage. And the contents of "df2" is not fixed when you performed the "except" operation on it. As per the spark function definition for limit:

> Returns a new Dataset by taking the first `n` rows. The difference between this function
>       and `head` is that `head` is an action and returns an array (by triggering query execution)
>      while `limit` returns a new Dataset.

since, it return a datset, will be lazy evaluation,

Below code will give you a consistent output.

```
var df = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11).toDF("num")
df.show()
var df2 = df.head(3).map(f => f.mkString).toList.toDF("num")
df2.show()
var df3 =  df.except(df2)
df3.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Looks like I have to be very careful while coding in Spark/Scala. Is not show an action? I performed show before except. And even if df2 is different at different run, why should I have elements from df2 in df3 at the same time? You mean codes doesn't execute sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to test this is to just create a new DF that has the values you want to diff.

```
val df = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11).toDF("num")
df.show()
val df2 = List(1,2,3).toDF("num")
df2.show()
val df3 =  df.except(df2)
df3.show()
```

Alternatively, just write a deterministic filter to select the rows you want:

```
val df = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11).toDF("num")
df.show()
val df2 = df.filter("num <= 3")
df2.show()
val df3 =  df.except(df2)
df3.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will not solve my final purpose. I need kind of pop type operation in a loop. My ultimate objective is not to select 1,2,3 only.

Comment: Seeing an RDD or dataframe as a single collection with predefined order will cause troubles for you. I looked at how the limit code is implemented in Spark and unless you have an order operation (like if you applied sort), the order of the resulting dataframe can be quite random. Help yourself if you want to delve more into Spark's implementation: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/limit.scala

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. My problem is not really in which order items are picked up. I gave  a list of integers just as an example. Even things are picked randomly but the except makes sure that those randomly picked items were excluded, then I have no problem. For example, it may pick 4,8 and 9.  But then df3 must be {1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11). It can be (11,1,2,3,10,5,6,7) it doesn't matter to me. I mentioned I need kind of pop, but pop not exactly in the LIFO principal in a stack. What still baffling me is that when I call show(), is it not an action item?

Comment: Here is the takeaway. Don't expect things to always happen in same order between runs. I am sure your `df3.show()` ****ALWAYS**** has 3 items removed, now which ones will vary so don't expect to be same the way you have it. Don't even expect them to be the same as the ones returned by `df2.show()`. `df2.show()` does one coin flip, then `df3.show()` does another. Probably different ones. Especially if you are running this in a cluster (say YARN or something), and the data are read from S3 or HDFS or something . If you run in locally, it should be "accidentally" deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

One could use a leftanti join for this if you have uniqueness in the column for which you are comparing.

Example:

```
var df = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11).toDF("num")  
df.show()  
var df2 = df.limit(3)  
df2.show()  
var df3 =  df.join(df2,Seq("num"),"leftanti")  
df3.show()
```